# Nunit 2.6 + Resharper 7 +NCrunch + visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper, ncrunch

I had a good time with Nunit 2.6 + ReSharper 7, but after I install Ncrunch, my Visual Studio 2010 just fell apart and I can't run Unit Tests inside the Unit Test Sessions.

Error Message:

```
The project xxxx has not been built
```

Typical setup would be

Project XXXX - No Main

Project XXXX.Test - Some Code

Some code in XXXX.Test

```
[TestFixture]
public class Entry
{
    [Test]
    public static void ThisWillPass()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1,2);
    }


}
```

Note: I did set the Configuration Manager to "build" on the xxxx.test

Please advise.

Comment: I just figure out , I have to use Nunit 2.5 to get everything back to work again

Comment: Heya, thanks for sharing! Can you put it into an answer, perhaps also share *why* that solved your problem or what triggered you to use that solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is your project set as AnyCPU? If not check the resharper settings for a setting that controls if the framework it uses running the tests is 32bit or 64bit and make sure it is set the same.